# Where is the tmp directory for apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am learning php and need to know the tmp directory on my apache server for this code. The script is hosted here /domains/domain.com.au/public_html

```
<?php
if ($_FILES[img1] != "" {
            @copy($_FILES[img1] [tmp_name], "/temp server location" .$_FILES[img1][name])




?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one. You will have to explicitly create a directory with appropriate permissions that you will use to hold the files.

Comment: cool, what permission shoule the directory be 777?

Comment: Of course not. http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml